# Rename [google-consumer-surveys] to [google-surveys]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Google Consumer Surveys recently rebranded to Google Surveys. Could we change the [google-consumer-surveys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-consumer-surveys) tag to [google-surveys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-surveys)?

Comment: Normally, I'd say you just ask a mod to rename the tag, but given it is only 18 questions, probably just as easy to retag.  However, is there any announcement of this change anywhere?  I looked and I could only find references to Google Consumer Surveys and no mention of a rebranding,

Comment: The main announcement is here: https://analytics.googleblog.com/2016/10/announcing-google-surveys-360-newest.html We've also launched an updated developer site at https://developers.google.com/surveys/, just this morning.

Comment: We'd prefer a tag rename as that preserves our created / viewed / active / editors stats - unless there's a way to port that info over the new tag?